# Overriding a virtual function with optional arguments

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, optional-arguments

Why is this printing `23` as output; my expectation was `33`. Could somebody please shed some light on this.

```
struct A {
    virtual void f() {cout << "1";}
};

/* Private inheritance */
struct B : private A {
    void f(int x = 0) {cout << "2";}
};

struct C : B {
    void f(){cout << "3";}
};

int main() {
    C obj;
    B &ref = obj;
    ref.f();
    obj.f();
}
```

Comment: Because `B::f(int=0)` is not in the override chain of `A::f()`; it is independent of either `A::f()` or `C::f()`. The signatures are different. Is your question more of why did the compiler choose `B::f(int=0)` rather than `C::f()` (through `A::f()`) since they would be called the same way?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533589/can-virtual-functions-have-default-parameters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `f(int x = 0)` method in the `B` struct does not share a signature with either the `A` nor `C` struct's `f()` methods.

Comment: +1. Because B::f(int=0) and `A::f()` are in fact, different, there are two possible candidates that can be called. Therefore, this call undergoes **overload resolution** rather than virtual polymorphism. The best fitting candidate is chosen, and in this case, it is `B::f(int=0)`. I can search the standard for the exact rule(s) of resolution that trip(s) this if needed, but that is ultimately the  fundamental reason why `C::f()` is not called.

Comment: I'm sure many people, including myself would be interested in that document if you linked it.

Comment: It's always good to add the relevant Standard quote if it's not too much trouble.

Comment: I'll do some surfing in the standard and see what bubbles up. Overload resolution is covered in C++ § 13, with 13.2  covering Declaration Matching and 13.3 covering Resolution (my money is on 13.3.2 Viable Functions, and 13.3.3 Best Viable Function, but rarely is the standard so straight forward).