# C++ virtual function default argument value

Tags: c++, class, default-value

the below  is my test code, i think it will output "Der:12"， but the result is "Der:11", any one can tell me why output this, and where is the default argument store?

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
class Base{
public:
    virtual void show(int i = 11) 
    {   
        printf("Base:%d\n", i); 
    }   
};

class Der : public Base{
public:
    virtual void show(int i = 12) 
    {   
        printf("Der:%d\n", i); 
    }   
};

int main()
{
   Base *p = new Der();
   p->show();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also here... [Can virtual functions have default parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533589/can-virtual-functions-have-default-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I'm not sure it's actually valid to override a virtual function with a different default parameter, and it's certainly not sensible. But on the other hand, the compiler is doing the right thing, even if it's contrary to your expectations.

```
Base *p;
p->show();
```

What happens here is that the compiler looks into `Base` for a function taking no arguments. There isn't one, but it finds the one-argument function and calls `show(int)` with the default parameter of 11.

But the function is virtual, and so because `p`'s dynamic type is `Der`, it's `Der::show(int)` that actually gets called -- but crucially, still with `Base`'s default argument of 11, but the default argument is looked up statically, not using run-time dispatch.

I haven't tried it, but I'd imagine if you said

```
Der *p = new Der();
p->show();
```

you'd get 12 output instead.