# Resolution of virtual function with default parameters

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, overload-resolution

**header.h**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
    public:
        virtual void display(int i=5) { cout<< "Base::" << i << endl; }
};

class B : public A
{
    public:
        void display(int i=9) { cout<< "Derived::" << i << endl; }
};
```

**source.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    A * a = new B();
    a->display();

    A* aa = new A();
    aa->display();

    B* bb = new B();
    bb->display();
}
```

**output**

```
Derived::5
Base::5
Derived::9
```

My understanding was default parameter functions were resolved during compile time using function overloading.  Virtual functions were then resolved during runtime using function overriding.

But what is happening is a mess.
How does the function resolution actually happen here?

Comment: `Default argument resolution is based on the static type of the object through which you call the function` (i.e. based on the pointer type). http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/90b9b8ee-ed5f-4ba8-93b5-612c4d906124/default-argument-and-inheritance-hierarchy

Comment: Note that you can work around this problem by overloading the virtual function with another virtual function without the paramter, which "forwards" to the one with the parameter. Like: in Base `virtual void display() { display(9); }` and in Derived `void display() { display(5); }`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is actually seen by the compiler like this:
*(The `display()` method is not actually there, but the resolving works in similar way)*

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void display(int i) { cout<< "Base::" << i << endl; }
    void display() { display(5); }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    void display(int i) override { cout<< "Derived::" << i << endl; }
    void display() { display(9); }
};
```

Now you should understand what happens. You are *calling* the non-virtual `display()` which calls the virtual function. *In more strict words: the default argument is resolved just like if the no-arg non-virtual method was there - **by the type of the variable** (not by the actual type of the object), but the code gets executed according to real object type, because it is virtual method:*

```
int main()
{
    A * a = new B(); // type of a is A*   real type is B
    a->display();    // calls A::display() which calls B::display(5)

    A* aa = new A(); // type of aa is A*  real type is A
    aa->display();   // calls A::display() which calls A::display(5)

    B* bb = new B(); // type of bb is B*  real type is B
    bb->display();   // calls B::display() which calls B::display(9)
}
```

Comment: Oh, this is exactly what I was looking for.Hey, but then how is `Derived::5` printed? It should be `Base::5`

Comment: When you invoke `a->display();` on an object of (dynamic) type `B`, it calls `display();`, that is the **non-virtual overload** `display()` which calls `display(5);` which is then **virtually** resolved to `B::display(5)`. And in the original code something similar happens. Instead of the additional non-virtual function, it is the default parameter which is resolved on the **static type**.

Comment: Hmm, this is complicated.

Comment: Note that firda's code is only a demonstration for better understanding what happens under the hood. The compiler does not really translate your code to this one.

Comment: @leemes I think, then it is a different question to ask how functions with default parameters are resolved?

Comment: Yeah but I'm sure it exists. I recommend you to read the linked question (duplicate).

Comment: I read it. But that didn't say how the functions gets resolved.

Comment: @cppcoder: [see the answer from Andreas](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25994811/1722660). I have placed non-virtual `display()` on both classes taking the default argument to *mimic* how it works, how it is resolved.

Answer (score 8):

There is no polymorphism on default arguments. They are resolved compile-time.

`A::display` has default argument equal 5.
`B::display` has default argument equal 9.
It's only the type of `a`, `aa`, `bb` variables that matters.

Use of different default arguments in polymorphic methods is confusing and should be avoided.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand: why `a->display()` is showing `Derived::5` and `bb->display()` is showing `Derived::9`? They are defined in exactly the same way...

Comment: @StefanoF Because `a` is of type `A*` while `bb` is of type `B*`. Hence, `a->display()` uses the declaration from `class A` while `bb->display()` uses the one from `class B`

Answer (score 6):

This behaviour is specified in *Chapter 8.3.6: Default arguments* within [Programming languages — C++ (ISO/IEC 14882:2003(E))](https://openassist.googlecode.com/files/C%2B%2B%20Standard%20-%20ANSI%20ISO%20IEC%2014882%202003.pdf) :

> A virtual function call (10.3) uses the default arguments in the declaration of the virtual function **determined by the static type of the pointer or reference denoting the object**