# Unexpected output for virtual function

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

Can somebody please explain why is the output of the following code is `B:2` ? How does the variable `x` get the value of `num` when there is no call to `A::print(int)`

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
  public:
    void virtual print(int num = 2) {
         std::cout << "A:" << num << std::endl;
    }
};

class B : public A
{
  public:
    void virtual print(int x = 22) {
        std::cout << "B:" << x << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A *a = new B;
    a->print();
    delete a;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I think that the point of the question is rather about the default parameters combined with virtual method calls. The answer should be here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533589/can-virtual-functions-have-default-parameters

Comment: Default parameters are not selected by the virtual function mechanism.

Comment: this is one of the reasons why default params are a bad idea

Comment: @pm100 I almost said that in my comment, but of course default template parameters are very useful.