# Function in derived class exactly the same as in base class but different default parameter

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

In read in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3533589/10220019) that you could override a virtual function with other default arguments, but that it is not smart to do. My case is slightly different from the question there. The function in my base class and the function in my derived class should do exactly the same only the default argument is different. How should I go about achieving this?

EDIT with some sort of code example what I think might work but violates what is said in the earlier mentioned post and doesn't seem very neat to me:

```cpp
class base {
public:
    //not sure about the virtual here
    virtual void func(bool something = true) { /*Do some stuff*/};
};

class derived : public base {
public:
    void func(bool something = false) override
    {
        base::func(something); /*Doesn't seem like the way to go for me */
    }
};
```

Comment: You need to post a code example.  Otherwise, it's hard to get what you're trying to say.

Comment: @L.F. I added some code

Comment: The linked question applies as well.  You will end up with `something = true` if you call `func` from a `base*` pointer.

Comment: @L.F. Yes I understood that from the linked question, but what should you do then to prevent this? BTW is the calling to ```base::func()```` in the func definition in the derived class how you would do this? To me that seems a bit of a stupid way.

Comment: You have to provide two virtual functions then.  What is the use case for this though?

Comment: I would avoid default argument for virtual, overload is an alternative (with drawback too).

Comment: @L.F. I can not really explain the case I'm sorry. It is to specific I can't think of a way to make it a bit more abstract. Can you explain me what you mean with two virtual functions? Do you mean two in Base class or one in Base and one in Derived?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to explicitly overload the function, and not rely on default arguments

```
 class Base
 {
     public:
         virtual void func() {func(2);}   // call func(int) with one default
         void func(int value);
 };

 class Derived: public Base
 {
      public:
         using Base::func;    // so the function which accepts an argument is
                              //   not hidden from users the class
         virtual void func() {func(42);}    // call Base::func(int) with different value
 };
```

Depending on need, it may be easier for the default value to be a member that is set by the constructor.

```
 class Base
 {
     public:
         Base() : default_value(2) {};
         void func() {func(default_value);}
         void func(int value);

     protected:
         Base(int defaulted) : default_value(defaulted) {};

     private:
         int default_value;
 };

 class Derived: public Base
 {
      public:
         Derived() : Base(42) {};    // set different default value in the constructor
 };
```

Depending on your need (and given that the requirement is only that the function be supplied with different defaults, but are otherwise the same) you may wish to consider leaving the functions non-virtual.

Comment: Is it necessary in your first code example that the func in the derived class is virtual as well? I'm quite sure that my Derived class will not be the base class for another class

Comment: In the first version, it would be necessary for the `func()` without arguments to be virtual if you use the base polymorphically, since you would essentially be overriding it to change how it calls `func(int)`.   You've only stated that the requirement is to have different default values - for that it is not necessary that `func(int)` be virtual, but (depending on other requirements of your classes) it can be.   If you make do make both `func()` and `func(int)` virtual, think through usage scenarios and then test carefully to ensure all use cases work as you intend if you override both.

Comment: So I'm I correct to say that if a function in a base class is virtual, the same function in the derived class should also be virtual? Like in general, always?

Comment: If a function in the base class is virtual, any override of it (with same type of all arguments) in a derived class is virtual, whether you explicitly specify that or not.  Overriding a virtual function does not make it non-virtual  (although, C++11 and later, you can use the `final` specifier to prevent further derived classes overriding it).

Answer (score 2):

You might have overload

```
class base {
public:
    virtual ~base() = default;
    virtual void func() { func(true); };
    virtual void func(bool something) // Maybe this one no longer need to be virtual
    { /*Do some stuff*/ }             // then using different name is appropriate
                                      // (avoid hiding issues)
};

class derived : public base {
public:
    using base::func;

    void func() override { func(false); }
};
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you use the keyword override in the derived class? I thought it was almost never really necessary

Comment: Not necessary but helpful. It allows compiler to warn you about mistake. `void func(int) override` would produce error.